# What kind of charger do I need to get for my Galaxy Tab?

Tags: samsung, charging, tablet, samsung-galaxy-tab

I have a older Galaxy Tab 1 I'm assuming because all it says on the back is Galaxy Tab Samsung. And I need to know what kind of charger I need to ask for when I go and purchase one or order offline so if anyone knows the exact name or what ever I'd appreciate the feedback thanks.

Comment: If memory serves, it's a 28-pin. Looks like an old apple charger port, but is a bit smaller?

Answer (score 0):

The original Galaxy Tab (GT-P1000) is a 7-inch device with one very distinguishing feature - the capacitive keys below the screen.

[image]

If this is indeed the one you have, you will need to find a charger or a USB cable with this flat connector on one end:

[image]

Given its age, it's quite cheap - sells for < $5 in my region. Usually just vaguely searching would give you reasonable results. You can just grab a cable and pair it with any modern USB charging adapter too.